# Terraform destroy instances when trying to scale

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I have The next instance of Terraform, then I add files and install software on the instance/volume. If I redeploy the Terraform plan to add another instance, this instance was destroyed and created a new one. 
How can I do for not destroying the instance?

```
#INSTANCE
resource "aws_instance" "DCOS-private-agent1" {
    ami = "${var.aws_centos_ami}"
    availability_zone = "eu-west-1b"
    instance_type = "t2.medium"
    key_name = "${var.aws_key_name}"
    security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.bastion.id}"]
    associate_public_ip_address = true
    private_ip = "10.0.0.14"
    source_dest_check = false
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.eu-west-1b-public.id}"

    tags {
            Name = "private-agent1"
        }
}
#VOLUME
data "aws_ebs_volume" "DCOS-private-agent1_ebs_volume" {
  most_recent = true
  filter {
    name   = "attachment.instance-id"
    values = ["${aws_instance.DCOS-private-agent1.id}"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Following the next issue: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/6416

My problem was solved replacing `security_groups` with `vpc_security_group_ids`.